# Trigger - Activador o Editar archivo sin permiso (no formulario) Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script

He creado un panel mediante doGet (panel HTML), vinculado a una hoja de cálculo. La misma agrega datos a la hoja de cálculos, y también extrae datos de la misma al ir seleccionando en una lista desplegable nombre de personas.

El inconveniente que tengo es que debo darle permiso a las personas para que editen el archivo (por más que lo hagan desde el panel HTML), y la idea es que esas personas no puedan ver el archivo , salvo unos pocos datos. El archivo se puede compartir a la organización sin que las personas se den cuenta, pero cuando cuando cargan datos mediante el panel html, el archivo les aparece en el Drive en la parte de "Recientes". Un formulario no me es útil ya que no extrae datos de una hoja de cálculos dinámicamente.

Probé con agregar un archivo tipo interfase, pero el cambio se debe hacer manual para ejecutar un activador, y por tiempo el mínimo es de 1 minuto, y es demasiado, ya que debe ser automática la devulución de la carga de la hoja de cálculo al panel html.

Answer (score 0):

El problema seguramente se debe a que has publicado tu aplicación web para ser ejecutada con las credenciales del usuario que la accede. Cambia esto a que sea ejecutada con tus credenciales. En inglés la opción se llama "Execute app as me" que en español se traduciría como "Ejecuta la aplicación como yo"

**Referencias**

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#permissions

Comment: Hola Rubén, muchas gracias por la respuesta. El tema es que el panel tiene una lista de empleados, que se muestran según el usuario que accede, entonces necesito de alguna manera identificar al usuario que accede, para que se muestren determinados valores en la lista. Igualmente me sirve de mucho lo que me explicaste , ya que eso mismo lo puedo utilizar para reemplazar formularios de google.
Saludos

Comment: @Diego1203 : Si no lo has hecho aún, lee [¿Qué hacer cuando alguien responde mi pregunta?](es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) . En relación a lo que mencionas de la lista de empleados, hubiera sido bueno que mencionaras eso en la pregunta. Podrías editarla para agregarlo o bien publicar una nueva. Me parece que lo segundo sería lo más apropiado.